# Subprocess unable to parse semicolon after do statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Trying to run the following:

```
command = "for i in `/bin/generateItems` ; do ; echo $i ; /bin/somecommand $i; done"
p = subprocess(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

And I get the following error:
No such file or directory

However, when I run the exact same code with the semicolon after do removed it works:

```
command = "for i in `/bin/generateItems` ; do ; echo $i ; /bin/somecommand $i; done"
p = subprocess(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Could someone explain why this is the case and is there anything I can do to have the command work with the semicolon after do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. You get the same error if you run the command directly in the shell, don't you? It's a shell syntax error.

Comment: you can try using square braces around the command ["for i in `/bin/generateItems` ; do ; echo $i ; /bin/somecommand $i; done"]

Comment: Why do you need that semicolon there?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference betweenthe two code blocks? Where did you remove the semicolon?

Comment: I get a different error, BTW: **bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`;\`**

Comment: That is the weirdest thing, it works in shell but please note that I am using Korn shell.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not valid* in bash to have a command separator other than a newline between `do` and the first command in the block.

Comment: Please note that I am using Korn shell.